# What does this book symbol mean?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-library, sitepages

In my sitepage library some entries have strange book symbols. What do they mean?
This is the first time I've seen this.

Apparently, it's a new thing.

[image: list]

Comment: Is it showing next to site page name or in another column in pages library? Also, can you please check if the Name column is formatted using JSON formatting or is it coming OOTB without any formatting?

Comment: It is showing inside the title column. There is no JSON formatting, it is a OOTB feature.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this icon indicates that changes were made to this page. Please republish to update changes.

After publishing, the icon will disappear
[image]

Comment: Can I also use this feature, if Content Approval is turned on?

Comment: @SharePointNewbie I turned it on and the icon still works

Answer (score 0):

The book icon in Site Pages library shows that "**The page has changes that are not published yet**".

It will indicate that the changes were made to the page and Publish to update changes.

[image]

Read more information at:

[Management and lifecycle of a SharePoint modern page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/management-and-lifecycle-of-a-sharepoint-modern-page-3410a04c-3ca4-4a4c-b867-33ab5c8bdcf3) - Check **Publishing from the Pages library** section on this page.

This will also work even if the content approval is enabled for Site Pages library.

Comment: Hi @SharePointNewbie, does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that this question will not be shown under unanswered questions list